# mongoDB error data base is connected but i can't stock my data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend, mern

so hello everyone i'm devolpping my authentication backend i set up my routers my models middlewares and everything then i tried to use postman to see if the registation work or not and each time i click on send request nothing happen i don't know what should i do exactly so please can anyone help with this

database/db.js // connection to database

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv').config();
const base = process.env.MONGO_DATA;


try {
mongoose.connect( base,
 {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true}, () =>
console.log("database connected"));    
}catch (error) { 
console.log("could not connect");    
}
```

models/user.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const validator = require('validator')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate: value => {
            if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error({error: 'Invalid Email address'})
            }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minLength: 7
    },
    tokens: [{
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]
})

userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    // Hash the password before saving the user model
    const user = this
    if (user.isModified('password')) {
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8)
    }
    next()
})

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function() {
    // Generate an auth token for the user
    const user = this
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.JWT_KEY)
    user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({token})
    await user.save()
    return token
}

userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
    // Search for a user by email and password.
    const user = await User.findOne({ email} )
    if (!user) {
        throw new Error({ error: 'Invalid login credentials' })
    }
    const isPasswordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    if (!isPasswordMatch) {
        throw new Error({ error: 'Invalid login credentials' })
    }
    return user
}

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

controllers/user.js

```
const express = require('express')
const User = require('../models/user.model')

const router = express.Router()

router.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
    // Create a new user
    try {
        const user = new User(req.body)
        await user.save()
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        res.status(201).send({ user, token })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }
})

router.post('/users/login', async(req, res) => {
    //Login a registered user
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(email, password)
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).send({error: 'Login failed! Check authentication credentials'})
        }
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        res.send({ user, token })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }

})

module.exports = router
```

index.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const userRouter = require('./src/routers/user')
const port = process.env.PORT
require('./src/database/db')

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(userRouter)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
})
```

so each time i try to see if i'm signed up or not postman didn't give any response he keep saying <> and no result  can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created " data " and " db " folder in your ' C ' drive?

Comment: Open Local Disk C. Create a folder named " data ". Inside " data " folder create another folder named " db "...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

- Create a folder on your machine with name **mongodb**
- Create a folder with name **data** in the **mongodb** folder
- Create one more folder with name **db** in the **data** folder

For more, refer [here](https://www.cuelogic.com/blog/install-mongodb-on-windows)